# Why Producer-Consumer code is not working?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore, producer-consumer

I am trying to code solution of Producer-Consumer problem with the help of Semaphores.
Below is the code I have written, on execution it is getting stuck after producing one number.

I have checked the assignment of both the Semaphore and it look fine.
The sequence of acquire and release methods being called also looks correct.

```
public class Q {
    int n;
    Semaphore consumerSem = new Semaphore(0);
    Semaphore producerSem = new Semaphore(1);

    synchronized void get(){
        try {
            consumerSem.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Got Data : " + n);
        producerSem.release();
    }

    synchronized void put(int n){
        try {
            producerSem.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Putting Data : " + n);
        this.n=n;
        consumerSem.release();
    }
}

 public class Producer implements Runnable{
   Q q;

    Producer(Q q){
        this.q = q;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i<20;i++){
            q.put(i);
        }
    }
}

public class Consumer implements Runnable{
    Q q;

    Consumer(Q q){
        this.q = q;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
           for (int i =0;i<20;i++){
               q.get();
           }
    }
}

public class PCRun {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Q q = new Q();
        new Thread(new Producer(q),"Producer").start();
        new Thread(new Consumer(q),"Consumer").start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should only use a single sempahore since you're only sharing 1 piece of data. Why are you using 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made `get` and `put` `synchronized`. So the producer goes in, locks `q`, uses the one permit of `producerSem` and blocks at the next `put` call. Unfortunately, `q` is still locked by the producer, so the consumer won't be able to enter `get`. To fix this, remove both `synchronized`s.

Now to synchronize the access on `n`, use `synchronized` only *where* `n` is accessed, not for both whole methods.

```java
    int n;
    final Semaphore consumerSem = new Semaphore(0);
    final Semaphore producerSem = new Semaphore(1);

    void get() {
        try {
            consumerSem.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        synchronized (this) {
            System.out.println("Got Data : " + n);
        }
        producerSem.release();
    }

    void put(int n) {
        try {
            producerSem.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        synchronized (this) { // invariant print + write, atomic
            System.out.println("Putting Data : " + n);
            this.n = n;
        }
        consumerSem.release();
    }
```

Comment: The internal shared resource `n` could be modified by 2 threads unless they're synchronized. Access to the semaphore should be synchronized.

Comment: @Jason 1. The `println` does that already. Notice that only one thread writes. 2. Then synchronize the access to `n`, not the whole method.

Comment: Yeah that is fair, access to just `n` could be synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 2 semaphores, only use 1. The value of `n` will ultimately be shared among 2 threads so it's the only thing that needs to be synchronized because Semaphores are inherently thread-safe.

```java
    public static class Q {

        int n;

        Semaphore available = new Semaphore(0);

        void get() throws InterruptedException {
            available.acquire();
            synchronized (this) {
                System.out.printf("Get %s\n", n));
            }
        }

        void put(int n){
            available.release();
            synchronized (this) {
                System.out.printf("Put %s\n", n);
                this.n = n;
            }
        }
    }
```